# Masonry hiding image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-masonry

I am trying to hide images on a grid I made using masonry. I dont know what wrong..help appreciated
The grid loads the images all fine, but when I click the button the alert shows up and nothing else

also how do I get masonry to fill the space of the hidden object, and can I get attridutes from the items ?

```
<script>
    //initialise masonry grid
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var button = document.querySelector('#button001');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        // options
        columnWidth: '.item',
        itemSelector: '.item',
    });
    //hide function
    eventie.bind( button, 'click', function() {
        //declare the variables
        var elems = msnry.getItemElements();
        var element = elems[1];
        var item = msnry.getItem( element );
        //hide the item
        msnry.hide(item);
        //reload masonry
        msnry.reloadItems();
        //show success
        alert("Success !!!");
    });
</script>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for the [`.hide` method](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#hide), it  accepts an array of items to hide.

Try with `msnry.hide([item]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out eventualy, had to actualy delete the item instead of hiding it

```
msnry.remove(element);
msnry.layout();
```